Seeming contradiction with respect to selective attention in preschoolers
I can't seem to make sense of a seeming contradiction between scientific research and my observation:
When my preschooler is watching a beetle or my 7-year old is playing Nintendo Switch and I say something, anything, really, the response is zero. I am invisible / non-existent.
Research on the other hand claims that kids have short attention spans and generally don't do selective attention but take in all information.
So why is it that I can't break my kids' focus? Why do they become so focussed and engrossed that they don't hear me even though they are supposed to have a short attention span and bad focussing skills?
Is there any research on this and if so, could someone please point me to it?

It would help if you cite the research you are referencing. The claim seems very broad and too simplistic for an actual research paper.
